# How do I transfer temporary CD files to bootable USB?

Tags: usb, live-usb, live-cd, cd, transfer

I created a CD with 12.04 and downloaded (and installed) a bunch of stuff. In Ubuntu, (running from the CD) I created a bootable USB with 12.10. How to I transfer my previously downloaded files to the USB?

Answer (score 0):

Running from the CD is a temporary environment - everything gets lost when you shut down the system. You can transfer files to the USB in a normal way. Transferring installed applications is incredibly difficult - reinstall them after intsalling Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: If you install an application inside a live CD/DVD/USB environment and then, without rebooting, install Ubuntu *with* that live CD/DVD/USB, the applications you installed in the live environment will be present in the system that is installed to disk.